# What is wrong with my code in my vbs?

Tags: vbscript

What is wrong with my code?

```
Option Explicit
Dim obj, x, y, v
set obj=createobject("wscript.shell")
x=inputbox("How many Beefs would you like to test?","WindowsDGK Beef Test")
if not IsNumeric(x) then
    msgbox"Please enter a number!"
End If
if IsNumeric(x) then
    do
        y=y+1
        obj.run "cmd.exe"
    loop until x=y
        v=msgbox("Do you want to run again?","WindowsDGK Beef Test",vbYesNo)
            if v=6 then
                obj.run wscript.fullname
            End If
            If v=7 then
                wscript.quit
            End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 variables in an if statement in VBScript. Example: y=(x) won't work because it think the input is a string and not an integer. You really need to edit you post.